# Is it possible to import vue-datepicker language via a variable

Tags: javascript, vue.js, datepicker, vue-component

I am using vue-datepicker plugin in my project. According to the docs, you set the language like this:

```
<datepicker :language="nl" />
```

And

```
import {nl} from 'vuejs-datepicker/dist/locale'
```

And

```
 data() {
   return {
     nl: nl
   }
 }
```

My question is: Is it possible to use a variable coming from a parent component or an env file to load all of this ?

So something like this:

```
CountryCode = "nl" //Coming from somewhere

<datepicker :language=CountryCode />
import {CountryCode} from 'vuejs-datepicker/dist/locale'
data() {
  return {
    CountryCode: CountryCode
  }
}
```

I know the code above is totally incorrect, but just trying to show what i mean, if that makes any sense.

Comment: What would be the use case for such maneuver? Abstraction?

Comment: Well, the language code comes from a mysql database. It is stored in the users preferences. So if there is another recommended way of doing is, i am open to suggestions. Still kinda new to vue.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken, the only types allowed for [a prop](https://vuejs.org/api/options-state.html#props) are:

- String
- Number
- Boolean
- Array
- Object
- Date
- Symbol
- Function

Even passing a Function is usually seen as an anti-pattern, unlike in React.

So, I doubt that this is possible and even if it could, it would be quite strange. So I don't recommend it anyway.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So what would you recommend doing when language is a user preference coming from a mysql database ?